# How to fully convert JSP scriptlet into JSTL?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jstl, crud

I am new to JSTL, could someone please tell me how to convert below JSP and HTML code to full JSTL with no scriptlet in the page?

I'd also be grateful for suggestions about some good resources to learn JSTL and advanced JSP concepts such as JSF and spring with CRUD example.

This is curd example taken from http://javaknowledge.info/?p=478. I took this example because I thought it is 100% JSTL implementation but I was wrong.

My IDE is NetBeans.

```
<form method="POST" action='UserController' name="frmAddUser">
        <% String action = request.getParameter("action");
            System.out.println(action);
        %>
        <% if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {%>
        User Name : <input type="text" name="uname"
                           value="<c:out value="${user.uname}" />" readonly="readonly"/> (You Can't Change this)<br /> 
        <%} else {%>
        User Name : <input type="text" name="uname"
                           value="<c:out value="${user.uname}" />" /> <br />
        <%}%>
        Password : <input
            type="password" name="pass"
            value="<c:out value="${user.password}" />" /> <br /> 
        Email : <input
            type="text" name="email"
            value="<c:out value="${user.email}" />" /> <br /> 

        <% if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {%>
        Registration : <input
            type="text" name="dob"
            value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" value="${user.registeredon}" />" readonly="readonly"/>(You Can't Change this)  <br />
        <%} else {%>
        Registration : <input
            type="text" name="dob"
            value="<fmt:formatDate pattern="yyyy/MM/dd" value="${user.registeredon}" />" />(yyyy/MM/dd)  <br /> 
        <%}%>
        <input  type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: What Servlet-Version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two types of scriptles:

- print the current action into system's out - there is no JSTL alternative
- if-else statement can be rewritten using

  ```
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>        
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test='${ fn:toLowerCase(param.action) eq "edit" }'>
      ...
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
      ...
    </c:otherwise>
  </c:choose>
  ```

Comment: you are welcome, kindly do specify best jstl/el tutorial on internet.   didn't got "print the current action into system's out - there is no JSTL alternative" plz specify

Comment: I was refering to the `System.out.println(action);` If you want to access static methods from jsp, you have to declare them as jstl functions, but there is no prepared tag in JSTL for it. And about good jstl/el tutorial? I can recommend Head first servlets and JSP, although it's a little bit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago i learnd alot from this videos:

https://www.youtube.com/user/3n3xus/videos

Too bad, its in German and eclipse.

You learn

1. how to write your own JSTL-Framework.
2. how to write and navigate in jsf
3. work with richfaces.
4. how to work with facelets.